# discod py json user not defined issue

Tags: python, json, discord, discord.py

I would like to make a bot with bank accounts but it says that user is not defined. I watched a lot of tutorials and searched around but I could not find a solution :O I am new and really not good at python I would appreciate every help.

```
@client.command()
async def balance(ctx):
  user = ctx.author
  await open_account(user)
  users = await get_bank_data(ctx)

  wallet_amt = users[str(user.id)]["wallet"]
  bank_amt = users[str(user.id)]["bank"]
  await ctx.send(bank_amt)


async def open_account(ctx, user):

  users = await get_bank_data(ctx)
  

  with open("mainbank.json", "r") as f:
    users = json.load(f)

  if str(user.id) in users:
    return False
  else:
    users[str(user.id)]["wallet"] = 0
    users[str(user.id)]["bank"] = 0

  with open("mainback.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump(users,f)
    return True
 
async def get_bank_data(ctx):
  with open("mainbank.json", "r") as f:
    users = json.load(f) 
  return users
```

Comment: Please, provide your full error description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about 'user' not defined error in that code. But I see a lot of other things are wrong in there.

1. `await open_account(user)`, this line is incorrect. The definition of `open_account` makes it clear that it takes two argument, yet you only pass one argument to it. This should throw "Missing one Required Positional Argument 'user'" which is also probably the error you are getting
2. `with open("mainback.json", "w") as f:` I am pretty sure you made a typo here, 'mainbank' instead of 'mainback'.
3. `async def get_bank_data(ctx)`, this function apparently takes an argument but does not use it. I am sure you know that function don't necessarily need an argument to be called. Also I don't understand why this function is a coroutine when there is no need for it to be.
4. Similarly, `open_account` need not be a coroutine as well. It also takes a `ctx` which is quite useless as it just uses that to pass onto `get_ban_data` which is useless as the function doesn't utilize it, as mentioned in point 3.